How to pull a list of YT channels with a range of 1000 to 2000 subscribers
Using Youtube API to try and get a list of Youtube channels with a range of subscribers but I get an error

Parameter 'order' value 'subscriberCount' is not an allowed value

I am assuming that subscriberCount is not an actual parameter to search by in Youtube API? If this is the case how or what options would I have to try and get this information? I have the Youtube API with a key and have been trying to use jupyter and python to get data on individual YT channels (I am successful in this) but I am trying to compile lists of YT channels now by subscriber count and trying to get Youtube ID.
I would not need the data to be organized by subscriber count (meaning small to large) just to return a list of YT channels that fit this one search field of having a subscriber count between x and x.
Have been trying this code:
api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"

# Get credentials and create an API client
youtube = build(
api_service_name, api_version, developerKey=api_key)

# Create a request to the YouTube API
request = youtube.channels().list(
part='id,statistics',
maxResults=50,
order='subscriberCount',
minSubscribers=1500,
maxSubscribers=2000
)

# Execute the request and get the response
response = request.execute()

# Extract the channel IDs from the response
channel_ids = []
for item in response['items']:
channel_ids.append(item['id'])

# Print the channel IDs
print(channel_ids)


As far as I know the Stack Overflow answer 69259093 is the one meeting your needs the most.

I don't see in the documentation the parameters you're using for retrieve that data.
